# What is the condition that two maps need to meet in order for their compositive map to exist?

Tags: vector-spaces

In the book that I'm currently reading it states that:

"Two maps can be applied one after the other provided the co-domain of the first map is the same as the domain of the second. This process is called composition of maps"

I'm just curious as to know whether this statement is fully accurate? Shouldn't it actually be something more around the lines of:

"Two maps can be applied one after the other provided the image set of the first map (say, Im(f) where the map is f) is a subset of the domain of the second"

Comment: By saying that codomain of one map should be the domain of the other, you are imposing your condition. This is because image of a function is a subset of its codomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both statements are sufficient for the composite function to be well defined.

All we need is that for every $x$ in the domain of $f$, we can define $g(f(x))$ so $f(x)$ should be in the domain of $g$